# Sequelize Giving error - if (dialectTypes[type.key]) { ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of null

Tags: node.js, types, orm, sequelize.js

Everything seems fine with my code. There is a customer table and address is the foreign table.But I am getting an error saying   **if (dialectTypes[type.key]) {
TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of null**. Here is my code-

```
module.exports = (sequelize,DataTypes) => {

    const customers = sequelize.define("customers",{
        customerId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primarykey : true,
            unique: true
        },
        firstname :{
           type: DataTypes.STRING,
           allowNull : false
        },
            
        lastname: DataTypes.STRING,
        username : DataTypes.STRING,
        email: DataTypes.STRING,
        password: DataTypes.STRING,
        mobileNumber: DataTypes.STRING,
        customerGroupId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        avatar: DataTypes.STRING,
        avatarPath: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            default: "/customer"
        },
        newsLetter: DataTypes.STRING,
        deleteFlag: DataTypes.STRING,
        mailStatus: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        status: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        oauthData: null,
        isActive: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        createdBy: null,
        modifiedBy: null

    })
    return customers;
}
```

This is address table -

```
 module.exports = ( sequelize,DataTypes) => {

     const address = sequelize.define("address",{
         customerId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
         address : DataTypes.STRING,
         countryId : DataTypes.INTEGER,
         zoneId :DataTypes.INTEGER,
         city: DataTypes.STRING,
         local: DataTypes.STRING,
         pincode : DataTypes.INTEGER 
        })
        return address;
 }
```

And this is my index.js file where i have associated customer and address table -

```
const {Sequelize,DataTypes} = require('sequelize')

const sequelize = new Sequelize('spurtcommerce','root','',{
    host:'localhost',
    dialect:'mysql',
    port:3308
});

sequelize.authenticate()
.then(()=>{
    console.log("Connection established")
}
)
.catch(error =>{
    console.log("Error connecting to db")
})

const db = {};
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

// for customer table--->
db.customers = require('./customer') (sequelize,DataTypes);
db.address = require('./address') (sequelize,DataTypes);

db.sequelize.sync({force:false})
.then(() =>{
    console.log("yes re sync customer")
})
.catch(error=>{
    console.log("error",+error)
})


db.customers.hasOne(db.address,{foreignKey:'customerId'})
db.address.belongsTo(db.customers,{foreignKey:'customerId'})

module.exports = db;
```

This is the terminal -
[image]

Comment: This is not the code that triggers the error... please publish a full stacktrace & the relevant code that triggers it!

Comment: Can you now tell I have added index.js file?

Comment: Which file/line triggers the error? did you try commenting out one of the following two lines and see if it's a specific model?
`db.customers = require('./customer') (sequelize,DataTypes);
db.address = require('./address') (sequelize,DataTypes);
`

Answer (score 1):

I was directly giving 'null' value in model . It should be this way -

```
 oauthData: {
            type : DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull : true,
            default: null
        },
        isActive: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        createdBy:{
            type : DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull : true,
            default: null
        },
        modifiedBy:{
            type : DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull : true,
            default: null
        },
```